# Only getting bottom of blackbody curve rather than whole function

Tags: math, matplotlib, plot, graph, physics

I'm trying to plot the blackbody distribution at T = 2.73, I'm getting a curve but not a complete one and can only see the very bottom of the curve. Any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import * 
from scipy import *

h=6.62606957e-34
c=2.998e8
k=1.3806488e-23
T = 100

f = arange(0,10000)
E = (8*h/(c**3.0))*(f**3.0)*(1/(exp((h*f)/(k*T))-1))

plt.plot(f, E*10000)
plt.title('Black-Body spectrum for T = 2.725K')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Energy Density (f)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Not sure what you expect (or even what you are seeing). I can see the curve in the frequency range 0 - 10000.

Comment: I'm expecting a curve upwards and then decaying exponentially after the peak, it should give the blackbody distribution but i can only see part of the upwards curve.

Comment: Blackbody function at 2.73 K peaks at around 100 GHz. Why do you only plot values from 0 to 10 kHz?

Comment: Also, the code you pasted seems to actually use 100 K instead of 2.73 K.

Comment: ok that makes sense, I am somehow unable to make it plot a range large enough to display the whole curve though

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
x = linspace(0,12,1501)
f = 10**x
eterm = exp(-(h*f)/(k*T))
E =  (2*h)/(c**2) * f**3 * eterm/(1-eterm)
```

I introduced the `eterm` exponential term to convert the overflow in the exponential into a less harmful underflow.

Check your sources and compare to [wikipedia on Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck's_law) to get the right formula.

You can now also use

```
plot(x,E)
```

to get the x axis in log-scale, since if you get the right end of the `x` interval wrong, the graph will be uninformatively squished to the y axis.